# Get the node text from multiple nodes using just one expression?

Tags: html, web-scraping, xpath, text

I want to extract Text 1, Text 2 and Text 3 from the HTML below in one go using XPath. Is that possible?

When I run

```xml
//div/strong/a/text()/../../../div/span/span/span/span/text()
```

I only get Text 2 (I haven't included the path for Text 3 just yet).

```
<div>
    <strong>
    <a>
    Text 1                            
    </a>
    </strong>
    <div>
        <span>
        <span>
        <span>
        <span >
        Text 2
        </span>
        </span>
        </span>
        </span>
        <span>
        <span>
        <span>
        <span>
        Text 3
        </span>
        </span>
        </span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have read several other questions, like these

[XPath: How to collect multiple texts fragments from an XHTML node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684559/xpath-how-to-collect-multiple-texts-fragments-from-an-xhtml-node)

[XPath expression: selecting text nodes between element nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39504330/xpath-expression-selecting-text-nodes-between-element-nodes)

but none of them applies to my situation.

Comment: `//text()` will give you all text nodes in a document.   Alternatively, *xpath1* `|` *xpath2* `|` *xpath3* will give you the union of the listed XPath expressions.   If you wish to be more discriminating, you'll have to clarify your requirements.

Comment: I am not sure I follow you here. The thing is that sometimes Text 2 or Text 3 is missing and then I am not interested in Text 1.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single XPath expression that will match all the 3 texts here separately.
As mentioned by kjhugnes you can use `//text()` to get all the 3 texts together since they are all inside the root `div` element.
You can get the text1 separately with `//div/strong/a/text()` XPath and the text2 and text3 with `//div//span/text()`

Comment: Hmm, the reason I step upwards to Text 2 (and Text 3) is that I don't care about Text 1 unless Text 2 and Text 3 also exist. Instead of what I try in my question, should I just keep the first `text()` and step up to T2 and T3 and just check their existence instead?

Comment: it depends on your specific needs / flow. You can validate existence and values of text2 and / or text3 first and only then to check / to get the value of text1. It is 100% possible here. You can use Xpaths I mentioned here for that.

Comment: My flow is completely manual. I execute this in the browser console once or twice for a specific site and then a week or month later I do it on another site with a similar structure (several "main cells" with 2-3 "subcells" with a text string in them that I want to extract). I then insert the text into a spreadsheet for further manipulation.

Comment: So, what is the question now?

Comment: What is unclear? I want a "one liner" that extracts Text 1, 2 and 3 if and only if, Text 2 and 3 exists, that I can execute in my browser console.